# Django Model with associated Weather per entry

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models

```
class Route(models.Model):
    start_destination = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    end_destination = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    length_in_miles = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

and

```
class Weather(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to summarize all Routes for a given tour in a Trip class like so

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    tripname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    routes = models.ManyToManyField('Route')
```

but each Route in the Trip Model should be associated by the weather at that time, so a Trip should look like this in the end:

```
tripname
routeA weatherA
routeB weatherB
routeC weatherC
```

and I don't want to include Weather directly in Route, because the same Route can be driven twice but with different Weather in another Trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a ManyToMany Relation between `Weather` and `Route` Model with a [**`through`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) relation. Like this:

```
import datetime

class Trip(models.Model):
    routes = models.ManyToManyField(Weather, through="TripRoute")


class TripRoute(models.Model):
     route = models.ForiegnKey(Route,related_name='weathers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     weather = models.ForiegnKey(Weather, related_name='routes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     trip = models.ForiegnKey(Trip, related_name='route_trips', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, you can put a function inside `Route` model to fetch a single `Weather` instance, like this:

```
class Route(models.Model):
   ...

   def get_weather(self, date=None):
       if not date:
            date = datetime.date.today()
       return self.weathers.filter(date=date).last().weather
```

Usage:

```
trip = Trip.objects.first()
routes = trip.routes.all()
for r in routes:
    r.get_weather()
```

Comment: nice! but shouldn't the linking be done in the Trip class?

Comment: Well, I am not aware of your use cases. But to me it seems, route has a relation to weather as it changes per route.

Comment: Seems like it'd be best as part of the intermediate "through" model between Trip and Route.

Comment: I have updated my answer. thanks for the edit @schillingt